How do I rewrite a book with AI?
I have a book manuscript already written the traditional way. It is non-fiction and related to architecture, specifically on holistic building and how a particular building, that was the passion project of two individuals, came to be built. It was originally written in a dry, academic style meant for architecture students.
But now the authors want to change the tone and make it more natural, conversational, direct and warm - like listening to someone speak.
Rewriting the whole book manually will be time-consuming, so I am exploring AI options.
Are there any FREE AI options currently, either directly usable or usable after some training effort, which can do this?
Preferably one that does not come with word count limits that will make me copy-paste thousands of paragraphs manually. I don't expect it to be perfect. Obviously a human editor will go over the whole thing for final corrections. Something where the style can be set in advance via options or by training (by uploading samples)

"the authors want to change the tone" - What's your place in this? Are you one of the authors? An editor?

what's the question exactly? did you try writing a prompt for chatgpt? or perhaps you don't want to send your whole book to OpenAI?

I think chatgpt at openai can do that.
So for example, gpt can generate the poem like 18th style. In that case, you can write the prompt like that:"generate the poem has 18th style. And this is the title or topic"
If your financial can be payed you can use openai api.
In that case, you should consider the tokens.
